# How to add permissions from URL path parameter to DRF ViewSet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an app that uses url paths like the following:
`account/<ACCOUNT_PK/project/<PROJECT_PK>/`

When using Django permissions, the permissions of the last parameter (in this case project) are checked, but also want to ensure permissions are checked for Account too.

```
curl -s -u test:password \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -X POST -d '{"name": "new_project", "account": 3}' \
127.0.0.1:8000/account/3/project/
```

In this example I need to check permissions for both the data given in the request, and the parameters in the URL.

I have solved this by creating a `valid_account` method for the serializer class, and also a custom permission inherited from `rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission`, but it is very dependent on paths not changing.   Is there an option that I'm missing or third party package that can do this?

I have tried different permissions classes, or adding `app.change_account` to permissions_required in the ProjectViewSet, but only get errors.

Comment: DRF docs recommend checking permissions in the `get_object` method. So you'd retrieve the object by path parameters, then check if the user has access to that model instance.

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm POST'ing to `project` for creation, then there's no object to get, and for other methods get_object should return a project. I'm wanting to make sure user is authorized in the account to do that

Comment: Ah, didn't notice you were POSTing that request. So I see that you're specifying account twice - in the url and in the request body. I'd recommend dropping the account parameter from the url and just validating it in the serializer. So eg post to `/project` (ex have a ViewSet for projects). You could still have `GET /account/<id>/projects` with object-level permissions, but project creation is simplified.

Comment: Also, if like the `POST /project` approach, take a look at the drf-access-policy project. It provides a `rest_access_policy.fields.PermittedPkRelatedField` serializer field that will validate the account id against an access policy you define. Disclaimer: I contributed the PermittedPkRelatedField type :)